# Put highlighted code in a word document using Apache POI

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, syntax-highlighting

I'm generating some docx file (using Apache POI) that has a lot of SQL code in it. Because I'd like that code to be colored in a Word document, I'm first generating HTML with styles that does syntax highlighting. Now I can't put that HTML in a Word document. Is that even possible (using POI)?

What I'd like to achieve is SQL code in a docx being colored based on a generated HTML (like exporting SQL code from Notepad++ as HTML and pasting it in a Word document). Any ideas?